# Tab Bar Items change colors

Tags: swift, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have tabBar with 5 items. My app start on first item and all has white color. When I tap on another item nothing change - this is clear, but is possible that when I tap on second item all the items change color to black or when I tap on third item their color change back to white?

Comment: Do you implement **func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, 
           didSelect item: UITabBarItem)**

Comment: This is it! Thank you for good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to achieve it you have to options depending on your setup, in both cases you have to implement the following method `func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem):`

- If you are using a *ViewController*, it will have to implement the *UITabBarController* and *UITabBarControllerDelegate*. You will have to set the delegate property to self, you have to do it in the `viewDidLoad` method:

  `self.delegate = self`
- If you are using a Tab Bar Controller Scene in your *Storybard*), create an instance of a *UITabBarController* class, in my example *TabViewController*, and set it as a custom class in your *Tab View Controller*.

[image]

Next, in both cases you will have to implement the following method:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) 
    self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great explain!